# Resize Frame Within Grid Row

Tags: xamarin, mobile

I am using xamarin with visual studio for IOS and Android

I am trying to add a scrollView to the same grid row that my Frame is on but because the frame is the same size as my grid row it cuts off the bottom of the frame (I believe)

What I've tried : 
1. Setting the RowDefinition to "*" and "Auto" but the frame increases the length with the grid and
2. Adjusting the scrollView height

I feel like my best option would be resizing the frame so it's smaller than the grid row, however heightRequest doesn't work.. I would love any suggestions.

Here is the code:

```
<Grid HeightRequest="400">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="130"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="300"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

<ScrollView Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="4"  Margin="0,20,0,0" HeightRequest="390" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never">
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="4" BackgroundColor="Red">
                <Frame WidthRequest="200" HeightRequest="300" Padding="0,0,0,0" CornerRadius="10" IsClippedToBounds="True" Margin="15,0,0,0">
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Image Source="satayChicken.jpg" WidthRequest="200" HeightRequest="200" Aspect="AspectFill"></Image>
                        <Label Text="Satay Chicken" FontSize="24" TextColor="#48b67b"  HorizontalOptions="Center" Margin="0,-5,0,0"/>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                            <Label Text="PREP TIME" FontSize="12" TextColor="#4a6356" />
                            <Label Text="COOK TIME" FontSize="12" TextColor="#4a6356" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Center" Margin="0,-10,0,0">
                            <Label Text="5 mins" FontSize="14" TextColor="#48b67b" />
                            <Label Text="12 mins" FontSize="14" TextColor="#48b67b" Margin="15,0,0,0"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </StackLayout>
                </Frame>

            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="4" BackgroundColor="Red">`

as you have defined the **StackLayout** `Orientaition="Horizontal"`,the **Frame** will fill the height by default.

if you want to resize the Frame height,you sholud set its **VerticalOptions** property

like :

```
<ScrollView Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="4"  Margin="0,20,0,0"  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never">
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"  BackgroundColor="Red" >
                    <Frame  VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HeightRequest="270" WidthRequest="200" Padding="0,0,0,0" CornerRadius="10" IsClippedToBounds="True" Margin="15,0,0,0">
                        <StackLayout>
                            <Image Source="satayChicken.jpg" WidthRequest="200" HeightRequest="200" Aspect="AspectFill"></Image>
                            <Label Text="Satay Chicken" FontSize="24" TextColor="#48b67b"  HorizontalOptions="Center" Margin="0,-5,0,0"/>
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                                <Label Text="PREP TIME" FontSize="12" TextColor="#4a6356" />
                                <Label Text="COOK TIME" FontSize="12" TextColor="#4a6356" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Center" Margin="0,-10,0,0">
                                <Label Text="5 mins" FontSize="14" TextColor="#48b67b" />
                                <Label Text="12 mins" FontSize="14" TextColor="#48b67b" Margin="15,0,0,0"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </Frame>

                </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

The specific size is set according to your requirements.

or you also could set Padding property to the StackLayout to resize the Frame location like:

```
<StackLayout Padding="0,10,0,10" Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="4" BackgroundColor="Red">
                    <Frame WidthRequest="200" HeightRequest="300" Padding="0,0,0,0" CornerRadius="10" IsClippedToBounds="True" Margin="15,0,0,0">
                        <StackLayout>
                            <Image Source="satayChicken.jpg" WidthRequest="200" HeightRequest="200" Aspect="AspectFill"></Image>
                            <Label Text="Satay Chicken" FontSize="24" TextColor="#48b67b"  HorizontalOptions="Center" Margin="0,-5,0,0"/>
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                                <Label Text="PREP TIME" FontSize="12" TextColor="#4a6356" />
                                <Label Text="COOK TIME" FontSize="12" TextColor="#4a6356" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Center" Margin="0,-10,0,0">
                                <Label Text="5 mins" FontSize="14" TextColor="#48b67b" />
                                <Label Text="12 mins" FontSize="14" TextColor="#48b67b" Margin="15,0,0,0"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </Frame>

 </StackLayout>
```

Comment: Absolute legend, tested both solutions and they work perfectly. Thanks!